# Cannot run any Perl scripts on Windows 8.1

Tags: perl, windows-8.1, strawberry-perl, activeperl

I installed Active Perl 5.20
and also Strawberry Perl 5.20 after uninstalling Active Perl.

In both cases, when I open cmd and type 'perl' I get:

> Unknown Unicode option letter ':'.

This error also prevents all scripts from running on my Windows 8.1 installation.

I uninstalled Perl and did a fresh install and it still doesn't work.

Are there dependencies that I need to install? 
I googled the error but the results pertain to Linux installations where the script specified something wrong. But I get this error when I even try to use any perl command line or script. So my problem is not a faulty script.

Answer (score 2):

That is the error message you get from using an invalid value for the `-C` command-line option. At a guess I'd say you have the `PERL_UNICODE` environment variable set to a string that contains a colon `:`.

Take a look at [*Command Switches*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) in `perldoc perlrun` for more detail on this.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem on windows 8.1 . The problem is that, once on installation, .pl files are not automatically recognized by Perl engine. So please select a .pl file and right click and say open with and set the default program to C\perl\bin\ inside it click perl.exe and recognize it. Once this is done your perl works flawlessly.